# Are there any non SO users attracted by Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I wonder whether the proposals are hobbies of users from the SE network.

Comment: It's a honest question, are there social networks involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that right now it is mostly SO users. However, as SE sites grow they will funnel other users into Area 51.

Comment: Agreed.  I know there are users on Area51 from outside the SE network (I have recruited some of them).  Proposers though?  Not sure yet and I'm too lazy to cross-index user lists.